# *args treated as single argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, args

I'm trying to make a function designed to call another function multiple times:

```
def iterator(iterations, function, *args):  
#called as:
iterator(5, my_function, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Note that the number of arguments here is variable: could 1, could be 2, could be 10.
fill them in based on the function that is being called.

```
def iterator(iterations, function, *args):
  for i in range(iteration):
    temp = function(args)
  return temp
```

The problem here is:
 TypeError: my_function() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

And this is because (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) are being treated as a single argument.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the same syntax when *applying* the `args` sequence:

```
temp = function(*args)
```

The `*args` syntax here is closely related to the `*args` function parameter syntax; instead of capturing an arbitrary number of arguments, using `*args` in a *call* expands the sequence to separate arguments.

You may be interested to know that there is a `**kwargs` syntax too, to capture and apply keyword arguments:

```
def iterator(iterations, function, *args, **kwargs):
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = function(*args, **kwargs)
    return temp
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, [unpacking the argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (a.k.a. splatting it):

```
function(*args)
```

From the example in the documentation, you'll see that this is what you need:

```
range(3, 6)    # ok
range([3, 6])  # won't work
range(*[3, 6]) # it works!
```